# click event not triggering in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am using leaflet.js for my application. The click event is not triggering alongwith the mouseover event.

```
   layer.on({
            mouseover: function (e) {
                L.popup().setLatLng(e.latlng)
                .setContent("Test")
                .openOn(map);
            },
            click: function () {
                alert("Click");
                map.fire("click", e);
            }
        });
```

I am using the custom marker instead of circle marker

```
     option.pointToLayer = function (feature, latlng) {
         var marker = L.marker(latlng);
                var icon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'Image/InvestmentIcons/environmentalflow.png',
        iconSize: [12, 12], // size of the icon
    });

                    marker.options.icon = icon;
                    return marker;
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need onEachFeature function defined to show what should be in the popup, then bind that to the layer, that way when you click on it it opens the popup.

```
var marker = L.marker(latlng);
```

should be

```
var marker = L.marker(latlng, {onEachFeature: forEachFeature})
```

Then define this popupContent with some HTML and the attributes from the feature. The Misc and Street are fields in my GeoJSON file.

```
function forEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    var popupContent = "<p> <b>" + feature.properties.Misc + 
        "</b></br>"+ feature.properties.Street + "</p>";

    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
}
```

The mouse over is also defined in the onEachFeature function, in this case it's running a function called highlightFeature that you defined before.

```
layer.on({

        mouseover: highlightFeature

})
```